# Access 2007 wont show Navigation Pane

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a Access database that normally opens to a switchboard. I want to see the Navigation Pane but it wont show. Even if I check the option for it to show. How can i get the Navigation Pane and the switchboard to show at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, Hit F11